# What's the deal with the saarthal door

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need the combination for it and can't find it any where. I have looked everywhere I can think of.

Comment: [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Under_Saarthal)

Comment: You better find it out, it won't be the first pillar puzzle you'll encounter in skyrim. :3

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This one is asking what the combination is. That one starts already knowing the combination, but is having trouble inputting it correctly. The answers over there don't include the combination or general solution.

Comment: If you didn't look at The Elder Scrolls Wiki (linked in the answer), then you didn't look anywhere, much less everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Under_Saarthal)

> Pillar Puzzle 1
>
> After several more rooms and traps, there will be a door on the second
>   floor near a broken coffin. Beyond there is a puzzle with six
>   different movable pillars. The correct position for each pillar is
>   shown on the wall directly behind and above them. This fact could
>   easily be missed if the Dragonborn were not up close to the pillars.
>   The Candlelight spell (or Night Eye) makes them easier to see. Once
>   the pillars are properly set, the lever can be activated to open the
>   gate. In the next room there are two wooden ramps. As the Dragonborn
>   nears the top of either one, a Draugr Deathlord, Draugr Wight or
>   Draugr Scourge (level dependent) arise. An effective tactic would be
>   to lure the draugr back to the pillar puzzle room and shut the gate.
>   The Dragonborn would then be able to shoot arrows at the enemy
>   whenever it appears from around the corner. Alternatively, a high
>   Sneak skill and a potion of invisibility could be combined to sneak
>   through the door near the top of the ramp, and close it. Provided the
>   Dragonborn were quiet, the draugr would almost certainly remain
>   unaware. There is a chest and other items to loot here. Beyond an iron
>   door, there are two rune traps to pass. Activating either trap using a
>   shout or magic will make noise and attract the draugr, while walking
>   over the traps will not. The first rune trap can be easily avoided by
>   walking around it, while second rune trap in the doorway can be jumped
>   over without taking any damage. Passing over the second trap means the
>   draugr is ultimately evaded.

and

> Pillar Puzzle 2
>
> Solution spinning puzzle pillar There are four pillars that give you
>   the solution to the spinning puzzle pillars ahead. The second pillar
>   on the left should be turned to whale first (because it turns the
>   other three with it.) Then, the first pillar on the left should be
>   turned to snake (that will turn the two on the right.) Next, the
>   second pillar on the right should be turned to eagle (that one will
>   turn the last one.) And finally, the first one on the right should be
>   turned to whale.

Took me 5 minutes to find this on google.